# Change Order of PHP Foreach echo'd list

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am generally new to PHP and I have recently worked on a new plugin. So this question may be pretty much simple to answer but I am getting confused.

Basically, I have this code:

```
<?php foreach( $tile_categories as $i => $tile_category ): ?>
            <li 
                class="tile-category
                <?php echo ( $i == 0 ) ? ' open' : '' ?>"
                data-name="<?php echo $tile_category->name ?>"
                data-slug="<?php echo $tile_category->slug ?>"

            >
```

which renders on my front end page like alphabetically like this:

[image: code output]

What I really intend to do is always have the "border category" last and the "square category" first. I am stuck at finding a solution to sort this list out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you take the `$tile_categories` data from? If it is from a database, then you could sort it through the query.

Comment: what kind of sorting order would you like to use? Is it reverse alphabetical order or just random order with the `Border Collection` the first and `Square Collection` the last?

Comment: In my opinion sorting is not the answer. If you know the order just hardcode the echo. Instead of looping just write echo $tile_categories['square']; then whatever you want second and so on.

Comment: @HastaDhana - it can be random and only the 2 categories are fixed. Square collection the first and Border Collection last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
<?php
  function order($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($b->name, $a->name);
  }
  usort($tile_categories, 'order');
?>

<?php foreach( $tile_categories as $i => $tile_category ) : ?>
  <li 
    class="tile-category
    <?php echo ( $i == 0 ) ? ' open' : '' ?>"
    data-name="<?php echo $tile_category->name ?>"
    data-slug="<?php echo $tile_category->slug ?>"
  >
```

You need to sort your $tile_categories object. This example assumes you wish to sort in descending order by name.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This worked! I never thought of this! Thank you very much!